# Masking decimal precision with commas

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, maskedinput

I have a situation where I'm trying to mask decimal length of varying lengths. One of the requirements is that the input needs to have a ',' between every 3 digits (inserted automatically). The precision of the decimals is fixed to what type they are (1 precision 2, precision, etc). So we could have inputs of the form

```
000,000.00

000,000.000

000,000
```

I've tried to create something like this in bootstrap as an alternative approach.  However I can't seem to do it with input groups setting the input-group-addon width with normal bootstrap styling.

[image]

I was wondering if anyone has come across a good solution for this sort of input.

Answer (score 0):

You could opt to use jQuery; for example, consider this script (it assumes an input with id `number`):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function reverseStr(str) {
      return str.split("").reverse().join("");
    }

    $('#number').on('change', function() {
      var value = reverseStr($(this).val().replace(/,/g, "")).match(/.{1,3}/g).join();

      $(this).val(reverseStr(value));
    });
  });
</script>
```

This script will apply a comma every three characters every time the input `number`changes (i.e. when input loses focus).

Check the snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function reverseStr(str) {
    return str.split("").reverse().join("");
  }

  $('#number').on('change', function() {
    var value = reverseStr($(this).val().replace(/,/g, "")).match(/.{1,3}/g).join();

    $(this).val(reverseStr(value));
  });
});
```

```css
.number, .decimals {
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #777;
  padding: 8px;
  color: #999;
  font-weight: 500;
}

.number {
  width: 150px;
}

.decimals {
  width: 50px;
}

.inputs {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dot {
  width: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="inputs">
  <input type="text" id="number" class="number" placeholder="000,000">
  <div class="dot">.</div>
  <input type="text" id="decimals" class="decimals" placeholder="00">
</div>
```